# Question about union of cartesian product of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Is $A \times (B \cup C) = (A \times B) \cup (A \times C)$ true for all sets $A$, $B$ and $C$?

Don't know how to even attempt this question. Any help or guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Let $(x,y) \in A \times (B \cup C)$. Then $x \in A$ and $y \in B \cup C$.

If $y \in B$ , then $(x,y) \in A \times B$, hence $(x,y) \in (A \times B) \cup (A \times C)$.

If $y \in C$ , then $(x,y) \in A \times C$, hence $(x,y) \in (A \times B) \cup (A \times C)$.

Thus we have shown:  $A \times (B \cup C) \subseteq (A \times B) \cup (A \times C)$.

It now your turn to show that

$A \times (B \cup C) \supseteq (A \times B) \cup (A \times C)$.